# Javascript debugger in Atom IDE

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, javascript-debugger

I have used atom for Javascript. I install Script package. I also install debugger package using the following command

```
apm install atom-ide-debugger-node
```

However, in Atom IDE,  I could not find any debugger button. I tried View dropdown menu and Packages dropdown menu, no luck.
Can anyone tell me how to use atom-ide-debuggeer-node in Atom IDE? My Atom IDE is 1.58.0 X64. I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This debugger package needs an another dependency package called `atom-ide-ui`. You can install by following command

```
apm install atom-ide-ui
```

After that restart atom and debugger should work then. Might have to disable linter packages.

Comment: It works. Thanks.